# I'm trying to create a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

> Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 10, column: 6, Trailing comma not
>   allowed.

Can anyone tell me the solution to this error?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "know your web policy",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Know the policy of web page",
  "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.jpeg",
      "48": "icon48.jpeg",
      "16": "icon16.jpeg",
    },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Policy16.jpeg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? *Line: 10, column: 6, Trailing comma not allowed* Doesn't get more self-explanatory than that

Comment: {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "know your web policy",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Know the policy of web page",
  "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.jpeg",
      "48": "icon48.jpeg",
      "16": "icon16.jpeg",
    }
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "Policy16.jpeg",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}

Comment: If I remove that comma, still I am getting the same error

Comment: Look at the line and column numbers of the new error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Trailing comma not allowed`

Remove the last comma in multiple places:

`"16": "icon16.jpeg",`

`}, }`

You can also use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to help you validate and spot errors quicker in your JSONs.

Comment: `"icon16.jpeg", },` should be `"icon16.jpeg"},`

Comment: @MadaManu-- Thanks dude! it worked and  jsonlint is very helpful.